# Transit in Denmark with a D visa issued by Norwegian Embassy

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, transit, paperwork, denmark

I have received a category "D" national visa issued by the Norwegian embassy. However the flight tickets that has been booked by my company shows that I will need to claim my luggage and change terminals (2 to 3) in Copenhagen,Denmark before I take the connecting flight to Stavanger, Norway.
I always thought that the D visa is as good as another Schengen visa and i can enter the Schengen territory through any country as per my itinerary.
However can someone confirm if I can clear the immigration process in Copenhagen airport with the Norwegian "D" visa.Or do I need to apply for another transit visa?

Comment: Yes, this is completely normal. See [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: Long-stay visas give _strictly better_ rights than ordinary Schengen visas -- e.g., they allow you to transit through other Schengen countries on your way to/from the issuing country even if your 90/180 day counter is exhausted.

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "change terminals from 2 to 3". For all intents and purposes Copenhagen has a single terminal -- only the check-in desks are divided into a "terminal 2" section and a "terminal 3" section. Everything airside, as well as baggage claim and customs, is shared. If you do need to re-check baggage, beware that after you claim the bag and exit customs you will be _right next to the **terminal 3** bag drop_.

Comment: "can someone confirm if I can clear the immigration process in Copenhagen airport with the Norwegian "D" visa?": you'd better be able to, because you will have to clear immigration in Copenhagen in order to reach the gate for your flight to Norway.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you didn't need to re-check the luggage, you'd still need to clear immigration in Copenhagen since that's where you enter the Schengen Area.

And yes, you certainly can do this on a D-type Schengen visa.